# jquery find textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code works fine at finding the value of price, which is held in a label field.  However I need quantity held in a text area, but it's not working.

Any ideas?

The Javascript:

```
 var price = parseInt(ui.draggable.find(".price").html().replace("$ ", ""));
 var qty = parseInt(ui.draggable.find(".qty").html());
```

The HTML:

```
<label class="price">$ 100</label>
  <input name="qty_1" type="text" class="qty" id="qty_1" value="1" size="2" maxlength="2">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting/getting values of form elements `val` method should be used instead of `html/text`.

```
var qty = parseInt(ui.draggable.find(".qty").val(), 10);
```

Also you should specify the `radix` in `parseInt`.

> `parseInt(string[, radix])`
>
> `radix`: An integer that represents the radix of the above mentioned string. While this parameter is optional, always specify it to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified.

Comment: Awesome, that was perfect.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

another solution

```
var
    price     = $(".price").html().replace('$ ',''),
    price_val = parseInt(price),
    qty       = $("input[name='qty_1']"),
    qty_val   = parseInt(qty[0].value)
;
```

you can merge these into two lines but sometimes it's easier to debug with expanded code.